# Redirection to external page within web forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect, webforms

I have a WebForms application ( .Net Framework 4.5.2) . I need to redirect some pages to external web page example www.google.com

I tried to modify the routes

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

        }
    }
```

I need to know

- What is the best way to do this ?
- How can I change my code to accomplish this task?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use just Response.Redirect method

Comment: @Sergey I need a global routing configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use [IIS Url Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for that. It enables you to add rewrites/redirects in web.config like:

```
<rule name="Rule1">
      <match url="somefunpage"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.otherdomain.com/" />
</rule>
```

You can also use regexp, wildcards etc. It's pretty powerful.